# Where to put my siteLanguage parameter (cross cutting concern?)

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, translation

In my project every page is translatable in several languages. For that purpose, I pass a sitelanguage parameter to each action. My custom base controller class catches this "siteLanguage" parameter and takes care of the further translation logic.

This works allright, only thing is now I have to add a string called sitelanguage to every action procedure signature just so my base controller can catch it. I don't do anything with this parameter in my actual action logic.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: How about using CurrentCulture and CurrentUICulture?

Comment: Firstly, they are unreliable. Secondly, it will be used in terminals where people of all kinds of nationalities work.

Comment: Unreliable in what way? You can set them based on Accept-Language headers, or whatever you like. They'll stay set, and will be used by all culture-sensitive code. If kiosk, allow user to choose, then set CurrentCulture from user choice.

Answer (score 1):

I'd put the site language in the session, and make the controller give it to the views, or  maybe, just maybe, allow the views to retrieve it from there.

I'd suggest Culture and CurrentCulture etc, but of course those don't work if you are an English speaking person who logs on from France.  I typically tie the language with the users' preferences in the database, though I appreciate your site may not require a logon as such.